# Adding ASCII Values together. Jython/Python

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, jes, ord

I need to get the word "COMPUTER". Convert each letter to its corresponding ASCII value (using For Loop). Then add the individual ASCII values together to get a sum.

I am entering "COMPUTER" as a parameter for 'text' when I launch the program.

So think COMPUTER = text

What i have so far:

```
def addASCIIValues(text):
  for char in text:
    AsciiArray = ord(char)
    print AsciiArray
```

---

1. Text is entered as 'COMPUTER'
2. for every character in "COMPUTER"
3. Convert every character to its ASCII Value
4. Add the values together
5. Receive a total SUM
6. Print sum

Please use simple code with no import functions.

I am using Jython but python responses would be ok aswell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your confusion might be because you have named the `int` returned by `ord()` `AsciiArray`.  It is not an "array".

This is simple using a list comprehension:

```
word = 'COMPUTER'
print sum([ord(c) for c in word])
```

However you asked for specific steps:

```
word = 'COMPUTER'
SUM = 0
for char in word:
    value = ord(char)
    SUM += value

print SUM
```

I should point out that generally UPPERCASE names are used for constants, and so the name SUM would not normally be considered good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ord function returns a int, you can just sum, so something like this

```
sum = 0
for letter in word:
    sum += ord(letter)

print(sum)
```